# Cannot boot from CD even if bios boot order is OK

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, hp-pavilion, password-recovery

I have to boot from cd on a HP Pavillon g6.

It has Windows 7 factory installed but the guy forgot his password.
So I made this Windows 7 recovery cd from another Windows 7 to try to do something.

The CD boot fine on the laptop I used to create it, but not on the pavillon.

I did go into the BIOS to adjust the boot order, but it didn't help. I can hear the CD turning at boot time but the computer won't boot from it.

The BIOS is a InsydeH20 version F.21

I googled and everywhere it tells to disable secure boot in the bios. The problem is that I don't have this option in the BIOS.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here? Or better, yet what I should try from now?

**NB:**

For now I am using the external display connected via HDMI, because the screen is broken (a new one is on it's way), but I don't think it's relevant for my problem.

[update]
I did a factory reset so I now don't really need to boot from CD.  But this question is still relevant for me : I want to understand what is the problem so I can face it differently next time (factory reset will not always be an option)

Comment: Did this guy, you're talking about, forget BIOS password or local account password?

Comment: Can you verify if it's UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: I can acess BIOS without password.  He just forgot his windows passwords.
I don't know if it's UEFI but I think it's not.  Otherwise I would expect to see more options in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

UEFI is different from BIOS, and can cause boot disks to "not work".

**Verify if the pre-boot system is UEFI or BIOS.** If it's UEFI, there will be a "legacy" or "BIOS Compatibility" mode which after enabling, should allow you to boot to the live CD/DVD. The boot disk you are attempting to use probably doesn't support UEFI.

Likewise, you can confirm this on your own system, to see if it is either UEFI/BIOS and has a "legacy" option enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine if it's UEFI.  But in the BIOS which I access pressing f10 at boot time, I have no "Legacy mode" nor "Secure Boot".  So I presumed it was not UEFI.